# How I apply a command to all lines?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

If I want to indent all lines in a document, I can type `>G` to apply it to the current line and below, followed by and `>gg` to apply it to the lines above.

Is there a combination I can use to just apply `>` to all lines at once?

Answer (score 19):

You are looking for the `:>` command and a range of `1,$` (`%` for short) for the whole file.

```
:%>
```

For more help see:

```
:h :>
:h :range
```

Comment: Because of the title of this question ("apply a command to all lines"), I feel it's worth noting that the example in the question mentions the Normal-mode operator `>`, while this answer uses the Command-mode command `:>`. These are not, strictly speaking, the same thing. That they have the same name should be considered a coincidence; don't assume you can interchange operators and commands in general. For example, the `gU` operator converts text to uppercase, but `:%gU` is *not* a valid command to apply the same to the entire buffer.

Answer (score 7):

One way to indent all lines in a document:

```
:%>
```

Answer (score 4):

Without leaving normal mode you can simply do:

```
gg>G
```

Comment: the downside here is that you lose your position in the file

Comment: All the other answers share that downside and the OP didn't mention "respect the cursor position" as a requirement.

Comment: <c-o>  can be used to go back to your previous position @romainl's solution requires you to go back twice while the other only require going back once

Comment: Surely you can appreciate the value of keeping your place, and how an answer that would keep that position would be valuable.

Comment: @TankorSmash, yes, but that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: That's why it's not being downvoted. It's simply a note saying there's a better option somewhere and that they should keep looking. For example, on a programming SE site, sloppy code that solves the problem solves the problem, but you'd still expect to find another solution that solves the problem and looks good.

Comment: @brettanomyces, use backtick-backtick to come back.

Comment: @romainl backtick-backtick i find is harder to reach on the keyboard, plus with your soulution at least backtick-backtick will only return you to the top of the file, not to where you were before the gg.

Comment: Nope, it brings me to the position before `gg>G`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option that has not been mentioned yet:

```
:g/^/>
```

This will run the command `>` on all lines that match the pattern `^`.

Downside is that this will overwrite your search history.